# reactjs custom component input value doesnt update with state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a list app, and I am having issues with the components not updating correctly.  I pull the users list from a JSON file and save it in a state.  I am using context to pass that state and other information around to my different compoents.  The smallest component is the user items broken out into a list which is editable.  It is here with the list of items that I am having issues with.

For example, I have two different JSON files:

```
    [{"userId": 81944,
        "listId": 1,
        "title": "testa",
        "items": [
            {
                "listItemId": 0,
                "product": "walnuts",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Bakery",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 1,
                "product": "syrup",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Beverages",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": true
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 2,
                "product": "cinnamon",
                "quantity": 6,
                "category": "Bakery",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 3,
                "product": "gabonzo beans",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Canned Goods",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": true
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 4,
                "product": "diced tomatos",
                "quantity": 7,
                "category": "Produce",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 5,
                "product": "milk",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Dairy",
                "unit": "Oz",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 6,
                "product": "salmon",
                "quantity": 3,
                "category": "Meat",
                "unit": "Lb",
                "cart": false
            }]},{
        "userId": 78863,
        "listId": 4,
        "title": "testd",
        "items": [
            {
                "listItemId": 0,
                "product": "half and half",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Dairy",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 1,
                "product": "Blue Cheese",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Dairy",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 2,
                "product": "Garlic",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Produce",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 3,
                "product": "Chestnuts",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Other",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 4,
                "product": "Balsamic Vinegar",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Other",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 5,
                "product": "Onions",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Produce",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 6,
                "product": "Flax Seed",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "others",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            },
            {
                "listItemId": 7,
                "product": "Plantains",
                "quantity": 1,
                "category": "Produce",
                "unit": "Each",
                "cart": false
            }]}]
```

In my app I have a dialog box that allows me to switch between my lists.  I then take list and pass it a custom component to be drawn on the screen.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';



const Card=(props)=>{
    //console.log('prop');
    const [cart, setCart] = useState(props.cart);
    const [Product, setProduct] = useState(props.item);
    const [Quantity, setQuantity] = useState(props.units);

    // useEffect(()=>{
    //  setProduct(props.item)
    //  setQuantity(props.units)
    //  setCart(props.cart);

    // },[])
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <li key={props.value}>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" checked={cart} onChange={(e)=>{props.cartChange(e.target)}}/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input id={'product '+props.value} className='update' 
                type='text' value={Product} 
                onChange={(e)=>setProduct(e.target.value)}
                 />
                <br/>
                <input id='quantityValue' className='update' 
                type='number' value={Quantity} 
                onChange={(e)=>setQuantity(e.target.value)}
                 />
                <span id='quantityType' className='update'>{props.unitType}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button id='save-button' type='button' 
                onClick={(e)=>{props.change(Product,Quantity,props.value)}}>&#10003; save</button>
                <button id='delete-button' type='button'>&#10007; delete</button>
            </div>
        </li>
    )
}
export default Card;
```

This is the code that calls the custom components.  You will see that I am calling it from a array.map() those arrays are fine, and have the correct information in them.

```
import React, {useContext,useEffect} from 'react';
import {DataContext} from '../../../context/test/DataContext'
import Card from './ItemCard';

const update=(x)=>{
    console.log(x)
}

const List = () =>{
    const {listId} = useContext(DataContext);
    const {userItemList} = useContext(DataContext);
    const {GetItemList} = useContext(DataContext);
    const {ListSplit} = useContext(DataContext);
    const {foundList} = useContext(DataContext);
    const {findList} = useContext(DataContext);
    const {Updater} = useContext(DataContext);
    const {cartUpdater} = useContext(DataContext);
    useEffect(()=>{
        GetItemList();
    },[listId])
    useEffect(()=>{
        ListSplit();
    },[userItemList])
    // console.log(findList);
    // console.log(foundList);

    return(
        <div>
            <p>To find:</p>
            <ul>
            {findList.map((item,index)=><Card key={item.listItemId} index={index}
                value={item.listItemId} cart={item.cart} item={item.product} 
                units={item.quantity} unitType={item.unit} 
                cartChange={cartUpdater} change={Updater} />)}
            </ul>
            <p>Found:</p>
            <ul>
            {foundList.map((item,index)=><Card key={item.listItemId} index={index}
                value={item.listItemId} cart={item.cart} item={item.product} 
                units={item.quantity} unitType={item.unit} 
                cartChange={cartUpdater} change={Updater} />)}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
export default List;
```

Each time I switch this, the props that I console log out change correctly.  Also, if I look at my compoents in dev tools (chrome) I see that the states should be correct, however what I see on the screen is not correct.  For example the second item which is cinnamon, if I switch to the second list should be Blue Cheese.  The prop changes, as does the state, but what I see on the screen is still cinnamon.

I know that I probably didnt explain it that clearly, but below is a screen shot of what I am talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close with the commented out code.  Since you are setting your props to state (which is a bad idea and I will discuss at the bottom), your `useState` only sets the state initially.  You want to watch these props and update when they do.

```
useEffect(() => {
 setProduct(props.item)
 setQuantity(props.units)
 setCart(props.cart);

}, [props.item, props.units, props.cart]);
```

The items in the array are what `useEffect` watches to know if it should fire.

As a side note - assigning props to state is a bad idea and you've seen why - they don't automatically update.  You should hoist up where these props are set to the parent and you can pass them down as props and use them directly.  You can pass down the setters as props as well, which can update the parent.

[This article](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e), while referencing class based React component may provide more information if you'd care to read up on it.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const initialItems = [
  {
    listItemId: 1,
    product: 'syrup',
    quantity: 1,
    category: 'Beverages',
    unit: 'Each',
    cart: true,
  },
  {
    listItemId: 2,
    product: 'cinnamon',
    quantity: 6,
    category: 'Bakery',
    unit: 'Each',
    cart: false,
  },
  {
    listItemId: 3,
    product: 'garbanzo beans',
    quantity: 1,
    category: 'Canned Goods',
    unit: 'Each',
    cart: true,
  },
];

const Parent = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(initialItems);

  const updateProduct = listItemId => (e) => {
    setItems(items.map((item) => {
      if (item.listItemId === listItemId) {
        return { ...item, product: e.target.value };
      }

      return item;
    }));
  };

  const updateQuantity = listItemId => (e) => {
    setItems(items.map((item) => {
      if (item.listItemId === listItemId) {
        return { ...item, quantity: e.target.value };
      }

      return item;
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
        All Items - (this state lives inside the parent component)
      </div>
      <div>
        {items.map(item => (
          <div>
            <div>
              Product - {item.product}
            </div>
            <div>
              Quantity - {item.quantity}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div style={{ width: "50%" }}>
        {items.map(item => (
          <Child item={item} updateQuantity={updateQuantity} updateProduct={updateProduct} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Child = ({ item, updateQuantity, updateProduct }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <span>
          Product -
        </span>
        <span>
          <input value={item.product} onChange={updateProduct(item.listItemId)} />
        </span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <span>
          Quantity -
        </span>
        <span>
          <input value={item.quantity} onChange={updateQuantity(item.listItemId)} />
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

A little example above.  The parent component holds the state of the items and maps over each to create a child component.  This example is a little rough around the edges.  You could do something like adding `data-id` and `name` to each input to simplify the updating functions, or use `useReducer` to hoist that logic a bit, but I think it gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the article, information, and fix.  How would I go about updating the input when I change the value?  That was the initial reason for using a state, so that if I changed the input then it would change as well.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example for you.  Let me know if you need further clarification or have other questions.

Comment: If this helped you, please feel free to mark this as the correct answer :)

Comment: How would I go about dealing with multiple children components that are different?  In my initial code, I was mapping over an array to create specific children.  In your example, when I create multiple children, they all have the same "item" state.  Also you have `Parent state of item - {item}`.  I don't recognize this, and couldn't find information on it.

Comment: Updated my answer.  Hopefully that helps.  And as far as the previously mentioned `Parent state of item - {item}` was just a little label I tossed in to help you understand where everything was living.